# AWS Key Management Service Durability?

Tags: amazon-web-services

What is the durability for keys generated by and stored on AWS Key Management Service?

The [Cryptographic Details Document](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/KMS-Cryptographic-Details.pdf) states:

> Durability The durability of cryptographic keys is designed to equal that of the highest durability services in
>   AWS

But I can't find clarification anywhere on what exactly that might be.

I know that S3 is highly durable (99.999999999%), and finding anyone ever having experienced data loss on that service is practically impossible. Given the above, statement I would assume AWS KMS to have similar or greater levels of durability than S3.

Has a documented loss of an AWS KMS key ever occured?

Comment: Amazon is not prone to provide clear answers to these questions without an NDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [KMS details page](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/details/):

> AWS KMS stores multiple copies of encrypted versions of your keys in systems that are designed for 99.999999999% durability to help assure you that your keys will be available when you need to access them.